# Firebase send FCM AND store data against uid in realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm just getting up to speed with the new Firebase products and I'm hoping some Firebase experts can validate my approach.

I'd like to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications to subsets (individuals & groups) of my app users. Crucially, I also want to store some information against each user's uid at the same time (in the Realtime DB). My `/users` node will look something like this:

```
/users
   -uid (the unique id created by Firebase)
       -firstname
       - ...
       - msgHistory
            -msgId
               -date
               -text
               -...
```

I need to update the msgHistory of all target users whether they've opted in to push messages or not. So, does the following approach make sense?

1. create my own list of target uid's for each group of users (I presume I can't use topics because I want to target users who haven't opted into push notifications too?)

then when I want to send a message to that group,

2. cycle through each of the uid's updating their msgHistory node and...
3. send a push notification if user has allowed it

**Assumptions:**

- All users will be authenticated (Email, Google & Facebook)
- At this stage I'm only concerned with iOS devices

Comment: I'm not entirely certain about your grouping mechanism, but aside from that what you're describing seems like a common approach indeed. Topics sound like a valid approach here too. Just call [`subscribeToTopic()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#public-methods) when your app's conditions have been met.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the comment & link to the method. In terms of a "grouping strategy", my app is basically a business directory so users will be grouped (targeted) by geo area, their interest in categories or interest in individual businesses. I can see how this lends itself to Topics but my query is whether Topic subscriptions can be used to identify subscribers so that I can store data (e.g. msgHistory in my example) on the user node. My assumption is that I have to store a record of subscriptions on the user node (or uid's in /subscribers node) to do that. Make sense?

Comment: There is no requirement that you maintain the topics the user has subscribed to, once the user meets a requirement subscribe them, and when they don't unsubscribe them. Then you can just send to the topics and only those users that are subscribed will get the messages. You could map topics subscribed against users for other reasons but for sending messages it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Its really good approach. I have created same messaging app for android using FCM and facebook login and its work like pro : check my Data format (json)

```
    {
  "chat" : {
    "armobiliya@gmail-com-doggieshome007@gmail-com" : {
      "-KN8QNQeARA3T5esXvn2" : {
        "message" : "hi doggy how are you?",
        "recipient" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2",
        "sender" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3"
      },
      "-KN8QSDUfGJwaao33nkd" : {
        "message" : "I am fine ...n you?",
        "recipient" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3",
        "sender" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2"
      },
      "-KN8QV1tuY5imq11EyhY" : {
        "message" : "me too",
        "recipient" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2",
        "sender" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3"
      },
      "-KN8QaYfdXmKuceLqdkP" : {
        "message" : "missing you\uD83D\uDE25",
        "recipient" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2",
        "sender" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3"
      },
      "-KN8Qd1PK_iFfKD6w8gL" : {
        "message" : "ohhhhh\uD83D\uDE0A",
        "recipient" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3",
        "sender" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2"
      },
      "-KN8Ql8-ONrsL3TdWfFO" : {
        "message" : "\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF82\uD83C\uDF82happy birthday",
        "recipient" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3",
        "sender" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2"
      },
      "-KN8QwIt0x08O-_Y4Sc5" : {
        "message" : "Thank you dear\uD83D\uDE18",
        "recipient" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2",
        "sender" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3"
      },
      "-KN8R5jX9ZKiFBpGhFd2" : {
        "message" : "\uD83D\uDE03",
        "recipient" : "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2",
        "sender" : "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "JY6HQlltFCUqps3YDzGYLat7YLC3" : {
      "avatarId" : 1,
      "connection" : "offline",
      "createdAt" : "1469036893226",
      "firstName" : "Doggies Home",
      "userEmail" : "doggieshome007@gmail.com"
    },
    "utb0d5LBQ0VOs8R0V3qJmNxeT9t2" : {
      "avatarId" : 1,
      "connection" : "offline",
      "createdAt" : "1469036965579",
      "firstName" : "Mobiliya AR",
      "userEmail" : "armobiliya@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```